# TinyMCE - how to remove toolbar2 and toolbar3

Tags: configuration, tinymce, wysiwyg, rte

I'm trying to implement tinyMCE into my site and I'm using the advanced theme, I've removed some options and set up the top toolbar how I want it to look but when I try to remove toolbar2 and toolbar3 they show up with default buttons.  Does anyone know how to remove them completely?  I've tried giving them "" and none and "none" etc - I've also searched for the answer and can't seem to find it.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
theme_advanced_buttons3         : "",
```

Comment: It's weird but I sword I tried that and it didn't work but it does now, thanks.